# Highchart export data using protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts, protractor

So I have an application written on the client side. It is just a regular angular web application. I am using protractor to do end-to-end ui testing on this application, however, protractor is limited to testing highcharts. What my main goal is, basically export the highchart data on the web application into csv so I could do some file comparison(By the way, I already know highcharts has the ability to export in csv, but do to specific reasons, I cannot use this approach) Right now, what I am doing is using protractor's method called getOuterHTML (http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) from this site. I am able to grab from highcharts-series-group div, but not sure how to use those numbers to get the real data.

I want to be able to grab the actual data points. Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/cqjvD/

On this website they have the chart rendered with series data
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

But when I inspect the highchart and look at the highcharts-series-group tag, I see

```
<path fill="none" d="M 18.708333333333 162.06 L 56.125 137.1 L 93.541666666667 116.16 L 130.95833333333 102.48 L 168.375 93.60000000000001 L 205.79166666667 74.4 L 243.20833333333 98.64 L 280.625 90.9 L 318.04166666667 50.16 L 355.45833333333 63.540000000000006 L 392.875 122.64000000000001 L 430.29166666667 147.36" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Why you are unable to use JS to extract data that you need? Can you add callback to the chart to add some custom shapes or edit SVG to include series data in it? Series data is in JavaScript, not in SVG.

Comment: @KacperMadej Thanks for responding. I appreciate it. I am using nodejs (server side) because of protractor meaning that I can't use client side javascript scripts. Also I am not able to edit the chart. This is an application I am testing so I can't change the internals of the chart. I just need to grab the data from the chart, put it into a file, and check it. The only reason protractor is able to grab the dom is because it's using something called shadow dom.

Comment: @KacperMadej Also since you mentioned that the series data is in the Javascript not SVG, does this mean that is impossible to grab the data straight from the DOM after the chart is rendered?

Comment: Data is not stored in DOM, so yes. However, your chart is getting its data from some source, so you should be able to grab that data before it is used in Highcharts. It is possible to [extend Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) and e.g. create additional hidden SVG element that will store the info you need in DOM.